# Static const member of private type

Tags: c++, c++11, static

I want to initialize a private static member variable of private type.

A minimal working example looks like the following.

`error.hpp` file

```
#pragma once

class error {
 public:
  error();
  ~error();

 private:
  struct error_desc {
    int code;
    const char *desc;
    error_desc(int c, const char *d) : code{c}, desc{d} {}
  };

  static const error_desc desc;
};
```

`error.cpp` file

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "error.h"

const error::error_desc desc{0, "Ok"};

error::error() {}

error::~error() {}
```

Obviously, this results in an error since `error::error_desc` type is private. Moving `error_desc` to the `public` section makes the program to compile fine.

Is there any other way to solve this issue still keeping the type private.
The only workaround I can think of is to enclose `error::error_desc` in a `detail` namespace and use it in the `error` class (which of course is not ideal), but I would really like to know a proper solution to this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to define a global variable named `desc` (which fails as expected because `error::error_desc` is `private`).

The correct syntax to define the `static` member `error::desc` should be

```
const error::error_desc error::desc{0, "Ok"};
//                      ^^^^^^^
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/35wx9rgHG9ijciII)

Comment: Ooops... A hasty question & a silly, careless mistake. Thanks for pointing this out...